# MultiValueDictKeyError varies in localhost and Heroku host

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, deployment

I'm currently learning django and I've created a simple TODO project which has an otp authentication feature. While running the project in localserver otp was generated and stored in the model which is then matched by using `if (t.otp == int(request.POST['otp'])):`  where `t` is a model object. This works perfectly fine. While I deployed the same in `heroku` server with `DEBUG = True` for testing purpose, it is throwing `MultiValueDictKeyError` in line `if (t.otp == int(request.POST['otp'])):`. Initially `t.opt` is set to the value generated and it is reinitialized to 0 once the user enters the correct OTP and registers. Kindly notice the `comments` in the code that explains the issue a bit more.

My `views.py` goes as (I've removed some elif part that are not required to reduce the number of lines),

```
def regsub(request):
    if(request.method=="POST"):
        uname = request.POST['username']
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        email = str(request.POST['email'])
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        try: **#this tries to get the values pass1 and pass 2 whereas except gets the value otp**
            if(request.POST['pass1']==request.POST['pass2']):
                dictpass = {
                    'username':uname,
                    'fname':fname,
                    'lname':lname,
                    'email':email,
                    'password':pass1,
                }
                
                the_otp = r.randint(100000,999999)
                try:
                    t=temp.objects.create(name=uname,otp=the_otp)
                    t.save()
                except(IntegrityError):
                    return render(request,'register.html',{'flag':True,'msg':"Username already exits! Please try again."})
                sub = "OTP for registration"
                msg = "Some Message " + the_otp
                from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                to_email = [request.POST['email'],]
                send_mail(sub,msg,from_email,to_email)    
                messages.info(request,"Password Verified! Please Enter the OTP sent to your email.")
                return render(request,'register.html',dictpass)

        except: 
            t = temp.objects.get(name=uname)
            if (t.otp == int(request.POST['otp'])): **#the flow directly hits here after saving the otp in the model(send_mail part is not executed in try), also throws MultiValueDictKeyError**
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=uname, first_name=fname, last_name=lname, email=email, password=pass1)
                t.otp = 0
                t.save()
                user.save()
                task.save()
                sub = "Account creation successful"
                msg = "Some Congrats message"
                from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                to_email = [request.POST['email'],]
                send_mail(sub,msg,from_email,to_email)
                messages.info(request,"Account has been created Successfully!")
                return render(request,'login.html')


    else:
        return render(request,'register.html',{'flag':True})
```

The above code works good in `localhost` whereas fails in `heroku`. I have used `heroku postgres` in production.

Comment: Several issues I can think in your code. 1) Perhaps the exception is raised by `send_mail` in the code. 2) You try-except block is **too** big. 3) Your except block is not very specific it should catch only specific exceptions if it is written for that. 4) Use `request.POST.get('pass2')` and similar if some value might not be present this will either return the value or `None`. 5) You have one view handling two things! This should ideally be 2 views.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yeah I might change it, but my point is, this goes completely fine in `localhost` but not in `heroku`.

Comment: instead of that `except:` (just before `t = temp.objects.get(name=uname)`) try writing `except MultiValueDictKeyError:` (`from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDictKeyError`). You will likely end up with some other error, which is the actual error you need to solve.